# Ruby: 2 word hash key separated by space

Tags: ruby, hash

What method is missing in my program to make the 2 worded states work like New Jersey and South Carolina and etc. I know by putting an underscore in between words would be easier but the user would also need to include underscore in their input which is not so cool. I would really appreciate any help. Thanks!

```
us_capitals = { 
 "Alabama"=>"Montgomery", 
 "Alaska" => "Juneau", 
 "Arizona" => "Phoenix", 
 "Arkansas" => "Little Rock", 
 "California" => "Sacramento", 
 "Colorado" => "Denver", 
 "Connecticut" => "Hartford", 
 "Delaware" => "Dover", 
 "Florida" => "Tallahassee", 
 "Georgia" => "Atlanta", 
 "Hawaii" => "Honolulu", 
 "Idaho" => "Boise", 
 "Illinois" => "Springfield", 
 "Indiana" => "Indianapolis", 
 "Iowa" => "Des Moines", 
 "Kansas" => "Topeka", 
 "Kentucky" => "Frankfort",  
 "Louisiana" => "Baton Rouge", 
 "Maine" => "Augusta", 
 "Maryland" => "Annapolis", 
 "Massachusetts" => "Boston", 
 "Michigan" => "Lansing", 
 "Minnesota" => "Saint Paul",
 "Mississippi" => "Jackson", 
 "Missouri" => "Jefferson", 
 "Montana" => "Helena", 
 "Nebraska" => "Lincoln", 
 "Nevada" => "Carson City", 
 "New Hampshire" => "Concord", 
 "New Jersey" => "Trenton", 
 "New Mexico" => "Santa Fe", 
 "New York" => "Albany", 
 "North Carolina" => "Raleigh", 
 "North Dakota" => "Bismarck", 
 "Ohio" => "Columbus", 
 "Oklahoma" => "Oklahoma City", 
 "Oregon" => "Salem", 
 "Pennsylvania" => "Harrisburg", 
 "Rhode Island" => "Providence", 
 "South Carolina" => "Columbia", 
 "South Dakota" => "Pierre", 
 "Tennessee" => "Nashville", 
 "Texas" => "Austin", 
 "Utah" => "Salt Lake City", 
 "Vermont" => "Montpelier", 
 "Virginia" => "Richmond", 
 "Washington" => "Olympia",
 "West Virginia" => "Charleston", 
 "Wisconsin" => "Madison", 
 "Wyoming" => "Cheyenne"
}

loop do
  puts "Enter a state to lookup it's capital:"

  state = gets.chomp.capitalize

  puts us_capitals[state]
end
```

Comment: Hello @deftool! Please [format your code blocks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) so that users can more efficiently read your code (and answer your question)!

Comment: thank you for the correction. I'm still trying to learn all these stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capitalize only formats the first letter in the string, thus it is not working with strings that contain multiple words. You can try to split your strings by space, capitalize each word and then join it back:

```
state = gets.chomp.split(' ').map(&:capitalize).join(' ')
```

[**Demonstration**](https://repl.it/Bxkr)

If you were using Rails, you could just use `titleize`:

```
gets.chomp.titleize
```

Comment: wow! Thanks potashin!

state = gets.chomp.split(' ').map(&:capitalize).join(' ')

totally worked well. However, if you dont mind. can you explain to me the map method? Im very elementary to this I just started to learn coding not 2 weeks ago.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose `gets` returns `"west    virginIa\n"`. Then

```
r = /[[:alpha:]]+/
state = gets.chomp.squeeze(' ').gsub(r) { |s| s.capitalize }
  #=> "west    virginIa\n".chomp.squeeze(' ').gsub(r) { |s| s.capitalize }
  #=> "west    virginIa".squeeze(' ').gsub(r) { |s| s.capitalize }
  #=> "west virginia".gsub(r) { |s| s.capitalize }
  #=> "West Virginia"

us_capitals[state]
  #=> "Charleston"
```

If `gets` returns `"West Virgin1a"`, we obtain

```
state = gets.chomp.squeeze(' ').gsub(r) { |s| s.capitalize }
  #=> "West Virgin1a"
us_capitals[state]
  #=> nil
```

Recall that [String#capitalize](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-capitalize) converts the first letter of a string to a capital letter (if it is a letter), but it also converts all other letters in the string to lower case.

Comment: Thanks Cary. Your solution worked pretty well too. Like what I told potashin, I'm on the early stage of programming. I really appreciate the help but to be honest the code looks too technical for my current abilities. If you have the time to explain to me what you did to the r variable and the gsub method that would be so awesome. otherwise it's ok. I don't wanna bother too much.

Comment: `/[[:alpha:]]+/` is a regex that matches a string of one or more letters. In the string "23aBcD ?e", for example, it matches "aBcD" and "e". A regex is an object, so you can assign it to a variable (here `r = /[[:alpha:]]+/`). `gsub(r)` is therefore the same as `gsub(/[[:alpha:]]+/)`. `gsub(r) { |s| s.capitalize }` uses the form of [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) that passes each string that matches the regex to a block and sets the block variable (here `s`) to the matched string. The value computed by the block is the replacement value for `s`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a helper method to convert user input?

```
#state = "new jersey"
state.gsub!(/\b[a-z]/, &:capitalize)
#state = "New Jersey"
```

- Credit to Jordan, in the comments

Comment: Or, more succinctly: `state.gsub!(/\b[a-z]/, &:capitalize)`

Comment: ah! I never realized capitalize made the tail end lowercase @CarySwoveland thanks... I saw your answer ^

Comment: `capitalize` is capitalizing a string comprised of the first letter of each word. You need to change your regex to match each word in its entirety for it to convert the other letters to lower case. Aside: I suggest you not thank a user for a suggestion in your answer. If you wish to do that, use a comment, to keep the answer clean. (Some may disagree.)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the simplest solution would be to make the hash keys lowercase and then `downcase` the user input.

```
us_capitals = {
  # ...
  "nebraska" => "Lincoln", 
  "nevada" => "Carson City", 
  "new hampshire" => "Concord", 
  "new jersey" => "Trenton", 
  # ...
}

loop do
  puts "Enter a state to lookup it's capital:"

  state = gets.chomp.downcase

  puts us_capitals[state]
end
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the OP may need the states to be capitalized in the hash for reasons unrelated to this question.